# How to open/change Google Ads opt out setting programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services, settings

Is there an easy way to help users to change their `Opt out of Ads Personalization` setting from within an app?

It can be opened manually from the Android Settings app by browsing to Google -> Ads:

[image: ads_opt_out]

I know lots of the Settings screen can be opened programmatically using the [Settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

However, I can't see an option for opening the `Ads` screen.

I also know that Google Play Services has some helpful utilities to let a user adjust their Location settings, e.g. [LocationSettingsRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest).

Is there anything similar for the `Ads` settings?

Comment: Hey, have you got the solution for this. I am also looking for the same

Answer (score 8):

For those who are still looking for the solution.
You can simply create the action string and pass that into intent.

**For Example:**

```
String action = "com.google.android.gms.settings.ADS_PRIVACY";
Intent settings = new Intent(action);
startActivity(settings);
```

This will open the Ads setting page.